# Is there a way to create a user or change a password with on-prem AD and automatically force the Azure AD linked account to choose a new password

Tags: active-directory, entra-id

Has anyone found a way to create a user on the on-prem AD and checking the default flag for "Force user to reset the password on next login" so that both that password and the flag will sync with Azure AD?  We opened a ticket with Azure support when first rolling out, and were told that the only way to reset the password for an Azure AD <> on-prem AD linked account, AND force the user to reset the password on next login,  is to reset the password in the Azure AD portal.  If you do that, it will sync back to AD, AND flag the AD account to require a new password on login.  But trying to do it from on-prem, just causes the sync up to Azure to fail.

The result of that, is we need to create our users on-prem, wait 30 min, then go to Azure and reset the password, so that when the user first logs in, they will be forced to change their password.  Very tedious.

We do not have any domain-joined workstations, so there is no on-prem way for users to actually change their password locally.  If we do NOT flag the account to force a password change and reset the password, it syncs up to Azure just fine, which is how we get them created in Azure AD.  But, then whoever set the password knows it, and the user isn't forced to reset it, which is bad practice.  My question ultimately is, is this truly how the system is designed, or has someone seen this and found a configuration that will allow for an on-prem password set/reset with the "Force user to reset" flag set?

Comment: You can always kick off a manual synchronization so you don't have to wait 30 minutes.

Comment: Thanks @ToddWilcox. In fact, that is was I do. However, we have a limited admin account for an MSP user that I want to delegate to, and we've restricted that user to only be able to admin a sub OU in AD, and not have access to other applications on the server. In the current workflow, they would have to create a user in AD, and wait until it syncs, then go to Azure to reset the password in order to flag the account.